# SPFX PNP ListView fails to load on page if it is hided and showed back again on the Modern page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have List View which i placed in the render part, page load i am hiding it via j query inside a div and when i show it back no data appears on it, but if i click on Developer tools it starts appearing or if i change the resolution of the screen it starts appearing. This is strange.

```
<ListView
items={this.state.supplierContractItems.slice(this.state.supplierContractRare, this.state.supplierContractFront + 1)}
showFilter={this.state.showFilters}
viewFields={this.state.supplierContractViewFields}
selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
selection={this.getSupplierContractSelection}
filterPlaceHolder="Search..." />
```

Comment: Could you share the full code for further research?

Comment: I can not enter the Complete code as this is crossing the limit of characters allowed, but to understand this in more detail, the listview placed inside a div and lets say id of the div is abc_id and i hide this div and when i show it back on the page the list view does not appear with any data, but if you just increase the resolution of the screen be pressing "ctrl + mouse wheel" up the list view starts appearing, this is strange, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce your issue.I use JS to hide div directly.

My test code:

```
export default class ReactGetListItemsAddtoSelectTag extends React.Component<IReactGetListItemsAddtoSelectTagProps, any> {
  public constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {               
      items:[]
    };
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetListItemsAddtoSelectTagProps> {
    
    const viewFields: IViewField[] = [{  
      name: "Title",  
      displayName: "Title",  
      isResizable: true,  
      sorting: true,  
      minWidth: 0,  
      maxWidth: 150  
    },  
    {  
      name: "ID",  
      displayName: "ID",  
      isResizable: true,  
      sorting: true,  
      minWidth: 0,  
      maxWidth: 200  
    }];  
    return (
      <div className={ styles.reactGetListItemsAddtoSelectTag }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>                
          </div>
          <div id="test">
          <ListView
  items={this.state.items}
  viewFields={viewFields}
  iconFieldName="ServerRelativeUrl"
  compact={true}
  selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
  selection={this._getSelection}
  showFilter={true}
  
  filterPlaceHolder="Search..."
   />
   </div>
   <input type="button" value="change" onClick={this.handle}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handle(){
    var div=document.getElementById("test");
    var style=div.getAttribute("style");
    
    if(!style){
    div.setAttribute("style","display:none");
  }else{
    div.removeAttribute("style");
  }
  }
  componentDidMount(){            
    let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);        
    web.lists.getByTitle("testn").items.top(5).get().then(items=>{
      console.log(items)
      this.setState({items})});
    
  }
  private _getSelection(items: any[]) {
    console.log('Items:', items);
  }
}
```

My test result:
[image]

**Updated:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getByTitle("testn").items.top(5).get().then(items => {
      console.log(items)
      this.setState({ items })
    });
   
    setTimeout(()=>$("#listView_id").hide(),2000);
   
  }
```

Comment: FIRSTLY THANKS A LOT  TO INVESTIGATE ON THIS, JUST TRY THE BELOW CODE

Comment: I Have just pasted a code above, please try that scenario that will show you the issue.  I Realy appreciate your effort.

Comment: It seems that this control has a rendering problem.You could submit a issue in its github.You could try my workaround in the updated code.

Comment: I Dont know  how can i put this issue in GitHub please  submit on my behalf if you can do from your end.

Comment: The work around you provided realy helps, but this fails when we use a toggle functionality, in toggle the other section fails to render if any refresh is done on the existing section.  DO WE HAVE ANY CODE WHICH CAN FORCE RENDER THIS ON CLICK EVENT??

Comment: Pnp list view github address:https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/

Answer (score 0):

```
FIRSTLY THANKS A LOT  TO INVESTIGATE ON THIS, JUST TRY THE BELOW CODE, THIS WILL FIRST HIDE THE LIST VIEW ON PAGE LOAD AND THEN BUTTON IS CLICKED TO SHOW BACK, IT ONLY SHOWS THE SEARCH BUTTON NOT THE RESULT, BUT JUST IF YOU`enter code here` CHANGE THE RESOLUTION OF THE SCREEN BY PRESSING CTRL + Mouse wheel up/down the result will show automatically. 


  export default class Reacttest extends React.Component<IReacttestProps, IHelloWorldState, {}> {

  constructor(props: IReacttestProps) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      selecteduser: []
    };

    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.props.context
    });

    this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
  }





  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReacttestProps> {
const viewFields: IViewField[] = [{
      name: "Title",
      displayName: "Title",
      isResizable: true,
      sorting: true,
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: 150
    },
    {
      name: "ID",
      displayName: "ID",
      isResizable: true,
      sorting: true,
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: 200
    }];
    return (
      <div >
        <span id="listView_id">
          <ListView
            items={this.state.items}
            viewFields={viewFields}
            iconFieldName="ServerRelativeUrl"
            compact={true}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
            selection={this._getSelection}
            showFilter={true}
            filterPlaceHolder="Search..."
          />
        </span>
        <span>  <input type="button" value="Click To Show" onClick={this.handle} /></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("People").items.top(5).get().then(items => {
      console.log(items)
      this.setState({ items })
    });
    $("#listView_id").hide();
  }
  private handle() {
    $("#listView_id").show();
  }
  private _getSelection(items: any[]) {
    console.log('Items:', items);
  }
}
```